# How to read the barcode from image using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, barcode

I'm trying to read the barcode value from image. I used [get_barcode_from_image.js](http://tobeytailor.s3.amazonaws.com/get_barcode_from_image/get_barcode_from_image.js) file but i'm getting either "false" or "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" value not getting the exact value.

```
<img id="barcode" src="barcode.png"/>
<br/>
<button onclick="alert(getBarcodeFromImage('barcode'))">Scan</button>
```

Any suggestions for how to get the correct value of barcode image ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you show the image?

Answer (score 2):

Try this option, look the links.

https://github.com/EddieLa/BarcodeReader

[Demo](http://eddiela.github.io/BarcodeReader/)

Comment: Where possible, it's better to include details of the answer, rather than just a link; that way if the link dies the answer still has value.

Comment: FYI Demo link is dead

Answer (score 1):

I found 3 solutions:

1. [QuaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/) library (open source) for reading barcodes, all done in JavaScript.

   Supports EAN, CODE 128, CODE 39, EAN 8, UPC-A, UPC-C, and CODABAR

   But you need to Choose Barcode type..
2. [webcodecamjs](https://github.com/andrastoth/webcodecamjs) Choose automatically but not supported well in Mobile.
3. this [JavaScript barcode scanner](http://eddiela.github.io/JOB/) also open source and free

   https://github.com/EddieLa/BarcodeReader

   and was the most acquired scanner (the other 2 wasn't deocode some barcodes).

   Atenntion that there is 2 changes need in **JavaScript barcode scanner** example for making it work:

   - remove the two require() in BarcodeReader, instead, add script tag with src pointing to the two js files: exif.js, DecoderWorker.js.
   - in exif.js, remove var before "root = this" to make root global. Otherwise, root is undefined.

   From [Here](https://github.com/EddieLa/JOB/issues/41)

Answer (score 0):

There is [Scandit Barcode Scanner SDK for the Web](https://www.scandit.com/scandit-barcode-scanner-sdk-for-the-web-press-release/) which is a barcode recognition engine written in C++. It's compiled to WebAssembly so it can run in modern browsers.

Here's a [live demo](https://websdk.scandit.com/) that uses the web or phone camera.

There's also a client library that can be used to process one frame like this:

```
<img id="barcode" src="image.png">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/scandit-sdk"></script>
<script>
    var image = document.getElementById('barcode');

    var canvasContext = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
    canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    var imageData = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height).data;

    console.log('Loading...');
    ScanditSDK.configure("xxx", {
engineLocation: "https://unpkg.com/scandit-sdk/build/"
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('Loaded');
      var scanner = new ScanditSDK.Scanner({
        imageSettings: {
          width: image.width,
          height: image.height,
          format: ScanditSDK.ImageSettings.Format.RGBA_8U
        },
        scanSettings: new ScanditSDK.ScanSettings({
          enabledSymbologies: [ScanditSDK.Barcode.Symbology.QR]
        })
      });
      scanner.onReady(function() {
        console.log('Ready');
        scanner.processImage(imageData)
          .then(result => console.log(result));
      });
    });
</script>
```

Links:

- [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scandit-sdk)
- [Documentation](http://docs.scandit.com/stable/web/index.html)

Disclaimer: I work for Scandit

Comment: I tried to use above code snippet, but I am facing with 'Cannot find package index.min.js.map@latest' error. unable to load the script. @mak